# Why does code-completion work on Stackblitz, but not in Intellij?

Tags: typescript, intellij-idea, code-completion, mathjs

Here is a simple repository to reproduce the issue: https://github.com/tmtron/mathjs-typescript-types

## Stackblitz works

Code completion works fine when we open the project in [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-xpwacl?file=index.ts):

[image]

## IntelliJ does not work

For some reason, code-completion in IntelliJ (2022.2.3 Ultimate) does not work:

[image]

When I **Ctrl+Click** the `MathJsStatic` import symbol, IntelliJ shows 2 options:

[image]

And it seems to use the wrong one (defined in `node_modules/mathjs/types/index.ts`):

[image]

## Question

How can we make IntelliJ use the correct types from `index.d.ts` (and ignore `index.ts`)?

Comment: In `node_modules/mathjs/types/index.ts` right-click menu, choose **Override file type > plain text** - does it help?

Comment: @Lena then ctrl-click works (i.e. takes me to `index.d.ts`), but code-completion still does not work (even after Invalidate-Caches and restarting the IDE). I found out however, that everything works, when I completely delete the `index.ts` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Update

The issue is fixed in version `11.3.1` [mathJs Fix #2812](https://github.com/josdejong/mathjs/pull/2812)

## Original

I think the issue is that the library contains an `index.ts` file and an `index.d.ts` file which are not related and this should be fixed by the library authors: see this [discussion](https://github.com/josdejong/mathjs/discussions/2809)

Workarounds for now:

- rename `node_modules/types/index.ts` to `node_modules/types/main.ts`
- or delete `node_modules/types/index.ts`